# Market reporting my manifest doesn't have a permission listed, when it definitely does?

Tags: android

I've implemented C2DM, I'm getting this exception for a small fraction of users (as reported by marketplace crash reporting):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
  ComponentInfo{com.me.app/com.me.app.MyActivity}: 
  java.lang.SecurityException: 
    Not allowed to start service Intent {
      act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER 
      pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) 
    }
  without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
  ...
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: 
  Not allowed to start service Intent {
    act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER 
    pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) } without permission
     com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:864)
  ...
```

I definitely have the "com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" permission in my manifest, it's working fine for thousands of users. Not sure why I'm being told these users don't have the permission requested?

Thanks

Comment: What platform version are you targeting as the lowest denominator? Because if you target an OS version lower than 2.2 the phones running any OS lower than 2.2 they don't have C2DM and cannot use it. This might cause the exception for them.

Comment: Hi Darwind, targeting 1.6 - but I have an if-statement checking platform version before attempting to register c2dm. So this shouldn't be the problem. I have thousands of users < 2.2, so would expect to see more of these errors if this was the case. Marketplace!!!

Comment: Ok, are there any consistency in what phones or OS that returns the exception?

Comment: Not that I can tell, says ~40 reports from device: OTHER. One user comment says they're running a Samsung Fascinate. No other way to see OS version or anything else that I can tell from the marketplace interface. I don't think there's any way to get in touch with these users either through the current marketplace interface?

Comment: Could it be that since the Market bug reports report the devices as "OTHER" that these devices fall through your if-statement for checking if the OS is >= 2.2?
The Samsung Fascinate seems to be running Android 2.1 as standard?

Comment: I have also been trying to tracking down this errors for the longest time. After looking at all the error reports, this seems like a very specific issue for 3.0 users. 

From about 1 million installs, I got 465 error reports for this exception. 

SDK Distribution:

7: 5. 8:47. 10:63. 13:3. 14:3. 15:341 (ICS). 

However, when I try to get the SDK Name distributions:

All the SDK names are either 2.6.35 or 3.0.8 (with different distribution endings).

What puzzles me is that 3.0 is only 0.51 % of my total user base and 4.0 (the real 15) is 15% of the total user-base.